# horizontal white space between div tags

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please let me know why the following code produces white space between the div "content-main', and the two introduction divs, which sit above the main content?

```css
.header {
  width: inherit;
  background-color: #58614E;
  height: 8em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.header-logo {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#header-home-link {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
}
.header a:link {
  color: #C5EBF9;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.introduction-left {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 55%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.0em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.introduction-left h2 {
  color: #57614E;
  padding-left: 13em;
}
.introduction-left p {
  color: #626262;
  padding-left: 2.0em;
  z-index: 2;
}
.introduction-right {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  z-index: 0;
  padding-right: 3.3em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 3.7em;
}
.introduction-right h2 {
  color: #57614E;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  left: 3em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
.introduction-right p {
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #57614E;
}
.content-main {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em;
  border-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content-main h3 {
  color: #728063;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">


</div>
<div class="introduction-left">
  <h2>Today's News</h2>
  <p>This website template has been designed by Free Website Templates for you, for free. You can replace all this text with your own text. You can remove any link to our website from this website template, you're free to use this website template without
    linking back to us. If you're having problems editing this website template, then don't hesitate to ask for help on the Forums.</p>
</div>

<div class="introduction-right">

  <h2>Testimonials</h2>

  <p>"You can remove any link to our website from this website template, you're free to use this website template without linking back to us.”

  </p>
</div>

<div class="content-main">
  <h3>Main Articles.</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: In this case a screenshot may be useful to show exactly what you're referring to.

Comment: do you not want white space between the divs? div's are going to automatically create space between themselves, hence the name <div> to divide the page into sections that you specify

Comment: You mean the space from the 1em border you put on the content-main div?

Answer (score 2):

I think because,you use

```
  .content-main{
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1em;
```

Try to use

```
    .content-main{
            background-color: #E2E2E2;
            border-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            overflow:auto;
```

In your css, I see (last Chrome in Linux)
[image]

when I use `border-style: none`, I get (second div with main-context without space):
[image]

It's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - not necessarily right:

Try removing all padding statements in CSS temporarily and see how it looks...

Then add them back in as desired.

Comment: And, I should have said - if you're using IE before version 9/10 then all bets are off

Answer (score 0):

The spaces between your elements are causing the white space to appear.  Put in some sort of wrapper and give it `font-size: 0`, then give the divs with text a `font-size: initial`, or if you care about making it IE compatible give it `font-size: 16px` or whatever, since `font-size: initial` doesn't work on IE.